# Each element of an array incremented or decremented till one of the element reaches zero.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic

There are $100$ boxes. Two players A and B are playing a game where A starts the game by inputting a certain number of apples into each one of the boxes. B will divide the boxes into two parts and A can chose one of the parts. The number of apples will increase by $1$ in all the boxes in the part in which A will chose and the number of apples will decrease by $1$ in all of the other boxes. The game ends when apples in one of the box reaches $0$. The question is to find the minimum number of apples that A should put initially so that the game never ends.(A wants the game to continue forever and B wants to end the game.)

MY APPROACH:

The game will definitely end if there are two or more boxes with 1 apple(The boxes with 1 apple will be put on two different sides by B.)  The game will also end if there are four or more boxes with 2 apples, 8 or more with $<= 3$ apples, 16 or more with <= 4 apples, 32 or more with <= 5 apples, 64 or more with <= 6 apples. So using this all 100 boxes with 7 apples should do the trick but I don't know how to optimize the solution to find the minimum possible number of apples. I am finding it difficult to continue further because there are two many possibilities and proving that a particular solution is the absolute minimum seems to be almost impossible.